# What server is hosting my SharePoint 2013 site

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have a requirement to brand SharePoint 2013 MySite. But in order to do that I need to perform Feature Stapling, and that requires Visual Studio installed on the machine that is hosting MySite. I had Visual Studio installed on one of the machines but was having the following error:

[image]

So I updated the hosts file as per this article:

http://tszulczewski.wordpress.com/2013/08/15/cannot-connect-to-the-targeted-site-this-error-can-occur-if-the-specified-site-is-not-hosted-on-the-local-system/

But I am having the same error. I am leaning to suspect that SharePoint 2013 MySite is not hosted on that machine. How do I find out what server is hosting SharePoint 2013 site. So I do not get the above error and can use Visual Studio to brand SharePoint 2013 MySite.

Much Obliged.

Comment: Central Admin -> Manage Web Applications -> SharePoint - MySites .. Check the URL field for the server

Comment: @Colbs Thank you for your comment, I do know the url, but cannot figure out the name of the machine that is hosting it.

Comment: ping the URL, then you can RDP with the IP

Comment: how many servers in the farm? what are the AAM settings formysite web applications?

Comment: I believe we have 3 servers on the farm

Answer (score 2):

Are you planning to do Visual Studio development against a **production** My Site host?

You should not have Visual Studio installed on any of your production SharePoint servers.  You should have a development environment and do your work there. Then, when your coding is completed you can deploy your solution package to your production machines via PowerShell or Central Admin.

Comment: I have visual studio installed on my dev environment.

Comment: good, then you should be all set. Just go to Central Admin and deploy the WSP.

Comment: does your dev environment have a My Site host? If not, you'll need to create one.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got VS to connect to mysite. I followed the following site:

http://www.mavention.com/blog/cannot-connect-to-the-targeted-site-error-visual-studio-2012-rc-sharepoint-developer-tools-host-headers

I added my local machine IP address to the hosts file and the site .. so it is (local machine IP address)       (site name) (with out the http:// and with out the port number). So if my site is:  http://mysiteSomethingSomething.com:101, I put, (local machine IP address) mysiteSomethingSomething.com in the hosts file and saved it.

Thanks.